# How to add a boolean datatype column to an existing table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I have a table called **person** in my database. I want to **add another column to the same table and it's a Boolean datatype column**. I have tried following queries but it says **syntax error** near default. I know this is a common and there are lot of answers. I have tried many of them and couldn't figure out to make it work. So please help me.

***queries I have tried***

```
ALTER TABLE person add column "AdminApproved" BOOLEAN SET default FALSE;
ALTER TABLE person alter column "AdminApproved" BOOLEAN SET default FALSE;
```

I have tried without **SET** key word too.

Comment: Nothing on Google if you search 'Boolean data type sql server'?? You are correct, this is extremely common and there are A LOT OF ANSWERS OUT THERE.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In SQL SERVER it is `BIT`, though it allows `NULL` to be stored

```
ALTER TABLE person add  [AdminApproved] BIT default 'FALSE';
```

Also there are other mistakes in your query

1. When you alter a table to add column no need to mention `column` keyword in `alter` statement
2. For adding default constraint no need to use `SET` keyword
3. Default value for a `BIT` column can be `('TRUE' or '1')` / `('FALSE' or 0)`. `TRUE` or `FALSE` needs to mentioned as `string` not as Identifier

Comment: Just a caveat here. BIT is NOT a true boolean. It allows 3 states, 0, 1 and NULL. It is subtle but very important to understand. Also you can't code against it like a boolean.

Comment: This creates a nullable bool.  This is correct : `ALTER TABLE [person] add  [AdminApproved] BIT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 44):

The answer given by *Pரதீப்* creates a nullable bool, not a bool, which may be fine for you. For example in C# it would create: `bool? AdminApproved`not `bool AdminApproved`.

If you need to create a bool (defaulting to false):

```
    ALTER TABLE person
    ADD AdminApproved BIT
    DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In phpmyadmin, If you need to add a boolean datatype column to an existing table with default value true:

```
ALTER TABLE books
   isAvailable boolean default true;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can do it.

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename`
ADD `column_name` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE 

ALTER TABLE `tablename`
ADD `column_name` TINYINT DEFAULT 0
```